# ¿Qué codificación debería usar en un XML con texto en español?

Tags: xml, codificación, utf-8

Estaba acostumbrado a poner en la primera línea de todos los XMLs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Lo venía haciendo casi sin pensar, pero luego me di cuenta de que las letras acentuadas del español se veían mal. Por ejemplo, en Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de ahí, lo resolví usando:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

---

Sin embargo, Wikipedia define a [ISO-8859-1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) como:

> **ISO 8859-1** es una norma de la
>   [ISO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizaci%C3%B3n_Internacional_para_la_Estandarizaci%C3%B3n)
>   que define la codificación del
>   [alfabeto latino](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_latino),
>   incluyendo los diacríticos (como letras acentuadas, ñ, ç), y letras
>   especiales (como ß, Ø), necesarios para...

y lista todos los caracteres del español.

---

#### Pregunta

¿Por qué se ve mal en Chrome, y qué `encoding` debería usar para incluir texto en español?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome no tiene ningún problema para mostrar texto codificado en origen como ISO-8859-1, pero no tiene ninguna forma de adivinar que esa es la codificación usada si no se lo dices explícitamente.

Considera el siguiente fichero:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<texto>áéíóú</texto>
```

Así es como se ve en Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto suponiendo que el editor de textos usado para generar el fichero realmente lo ha guardado en ISO-8859-1, claro.

Sobre la pregunta "¿Qué codificación debería usar?", pues realmente depende del contexto. Si se cumple que o bien 1) el generador y el consumidor del texto están de acuerdo en la codificación que se va a usar, o  bien 2) existe un mecanismo explícito para manifestar cuál es la codificación del texto (la directiva `<?xml?>` para ficheros XML, o la cabecera `Content-Type` para MIME y HTTP), no habrá problemas.

Dicho esto, hoy en día parece existir el consenso oficioso de usar UTF-8 como la codificación predeterminada para todo, por una serie de razones que están resumidas en sitios como por ejemplo este (en inglés): http://utf8everywhere.org

Comment: Yo estoy teniendo un problema similar. En mi caso uso codificación utf-8 y por lo que he comprobado si el archivo tiene la  [Marca de orden de bytes (BOM)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes_(BOM)) se muestran correctamente. Ahora sigo investigando como hacer que la incluya automáticamente el [XMLSerializer de .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @rsciriano Si usas UTF-8, **no incluyas marca de orden**: no es necesaria y muchas de las herramientas que trabajan con UTF-8 y no se la esperan pueden comportarse mal.  Por ejemplo, un fichero UTF-8 con *hashbang* de unix se vuelve imposible de ejecutar directamente si la contiene.

Comment: @Darkhogg tienes razón, **la marca de orden** no soluciona nada y **es mejor no incluirla**. Además lo que tenía yo era un problema de interoperabilidad al guardar en disco. Por cierto, estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de [pzin](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/317/602), cualquiera de las dos codificaciones funciona pero es importante que **la codificación real del archivo sea la correcta**

Comment: La códificación ISO-8859-15 es la versión actualizada de la ISO-8859-1, contiene algún símbolo más.

Answer (score 7):

Ambas codificaciones te valen.

Los problemas de codificación en la mayoría de los casos vienen porque **no se guarda el archivo con la codificación que se indica en el código del archivo**.

Esto habitualmente en el procesador de textos que uses, existe alguna opción para guardar el archivo con la codificación que necesites. Si hay discrepancias entre ambas opciones, es normal que no se vea bien.

Otro problema podría ser, menos habitual, que se estuvieran enviando cabeceras HTTP indicando otra codificación.

Resumiendo, tienes que asegurarte de que todas las indicaciones a la codificación tengan la misma información.

Comment: Totalmente acertado. Cambié el código para que fuerce el uso de la misma codificación al momento de grabar el archivo y funcionó. (Difícil decisión, voté tu respuesta pero elegí la que me parecía más completa)

Answer (score 4):

El texto que has escrito está realmente en `utf-8`, y lo estás tratando como si fuera `iso-8859-1`.

Una pista clara es que aparecen 2 bytes por carácter acentuado.

```
echo "á é í ó ú Á É Í Ó Ú ñ Ñ" | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 
Ã¡ Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº Ã Ã Ã Ã Ã Ã± Ã
```

Para XML, es recomendable usar `utf-8`. La especificación XML obliga a dar soporte a `utf-8` (y a `utf-16`, pero yo recomendaría usar `utf-8` preferentemente).

Comment: @Mariano Difícilmente, es una codificación muy extendida.

Comment: +1 Buen uso de iconv.

Answer (score 1):

A parte de lo que han comentado los compañeros, dentro de `Chrome` puedes especificar la codificación a la hora de mostrar el documento:

1. Menú de Chrome.
2. Mas Herramientas.
3. Codificación.

Comment: Si bien no responde a la pregunta, es un dato sumamente útil, mostrando cómo arreglarlo.

Comment: Respuesta útil, sí, pero quizá debería haber sido un comentario.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor opción, insistiría yo, es el [UTF-8](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).  El motivo es que el UTF-8 permite la codificación de todos los caracteres del estándar [Unicode](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) en el mismo documento, sin recurrir a secuencias de escape ("escape sequences") en la sintaxis del formato del documento (en este caso XML).

La segunda mejor opción es el [ISO-8859-15](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-15).  Este código es una revisión más nueva del antiguo ISO-8859-1, con algunos cambios pequeños.  Pero entre estos cambios hay uno muy importante:

1. El ISO-8859-15 contiene el símbolo del Euro (€).
2. El ISO-8859-1 se fijó antes de que existiera el Euro, así que no contiene el símbolo.

Y este ejemplo muestra por qué el UTF-8 es la mejor opción.  El UTF-8 permite codificar cualquier texto Unicode, el estándar internacional y dominante al cual se le añaden nuevos caracteres periódicamente.  Una aplicación que usa UTF-8 generalmente no necesita de cambios cuando se introducen nuevos caracteres como el símbolo del Euro.  Y adicionalmente con UTF-8 el documento puede mezclar texto escrito en muchos idiomas diferentes.  Con UTF-8 se puede escribir sencillamente un diccionario chino/español, pero el ISO-8859-15 ni el ISO-8859-1 permiten tal uso.

Comment: Muy buen ejemplo al final! Al describir el motivo, marcaste que no necesita secuencias de escape... ¿En qué sentido no usa escapes que otra codificación sí use?

Comment: @Mariano Los escapes en cuestión no pertenecen a el código de caracteres, sino al formato del archivo. Por ejemplo en HTML y XML existen formatos de escape como `&#x4eba;` que permiten especificar cualquier caracter Unicode en un documento codificado en ASCII. Esto es porque los autores de los formatos HTML/XML previeron la necesidad de referirse a caracteres que no existen en el código usado en el documento; sin tal previsión sería imposible. Pero el UTF-8 permite simplemente escribir "人" ("persona" en chino) en el documento.

Answer (score 1):

1. Para español es recomendable usar **utf8**
2. En el encabezado del XML se debe declarar la codificación **utf8**
3. Lo más importante: El archivo debe estar codificado como **utf8**

Para asegurarte de que el archivo está bien codificado usar un editor como Notepad++ o similar. A veces puedes tener la Base de Datos en utf8, el texto en utf8, las declaraciones en utf8 y toda tu vida en utf8 pero si el archivo lo guardaste como iso-8859-1 ya valió...